# What will happen if more alarms occurred than the license limitation in thingsboard?

Tags: licensing, thingsboard

If I had a Cloud Maker license, that has an alarm creation limitation of  200 per month, what will be the TB behavior if more than 200 alarms have occurred?  Does it mean that TB will stop generating alarms until the start of a new month subscription?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The Thingsboard will stop generating the new alarms.